MongoDB Aggregation nested $group
I am trying to render statistics in a single aggregation request. Grouping and sub grouping !
const [
    { type: "agency", properties: 4 },
    { type: "host", properties: 5 },
    { type: "agency", properties: 4 },
    { type: "landlord", properties: 5 },
    { type: "agency", properties: 8 },
    { type: "tenant", properties: 2 },
    { type: "host", properties: 1 },
    { type: "host", properties: 1 },
    { type: "agency", properties: 8 },
    { type: "host", properties: 9 },
    { type: "host", properties: 5 },
    { type: "agency", properties: 1 },
    { type: "agency", properties: 2 },
    { type: "tenant", properties: 2 },
    { type: "agency", properties: 1 },
    { type: "tenant", properties: 4 },
    { type: "tenant", properties: 7 }
];

pipeline.push({
    $group: {
        _id: "$type",
        count: { $count: {} },
        "0 property": {
            $sum: {
                "properties": {
                    $eq: 0
                }
            }
        },
        "1 property": {
            $sum: {
                "properties": {
                    $eq: 1
                }
            }
        },
        "2 properties": {
            $sum: {
                "properties": {
                    $eq: 2
                }
            }
        },
        "3 or more properties": {
            $sum: {
                "properties": {
                    $gte: 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

Desired result
[
    {
        type: "tenant",
        count: 4, // THERE ARE 4 TENANTS TOTAL
        "0 properties": 0, // 0 TENANTS WHERE PROPERTIES = 0
        "1 property": 0, // 0 TENANTS WHERE PROPERTIES = 1
        "2 properties": 2, // 2 TENANTS WHERE PROPERTIES = 2
        "3 or more properties": 2 // 2 TENANTS WHERE PROPERTIES >= 3
    },
    {
        type: "landlord",
        count: 1, // THERE IS 1 LANDLORD TOTAL
        "0 properties": 0,
        "1 property": 0,
        "2 properties": 0,
        "3 or more properties": 1
    },
    {
        type: "agency",
        count: 7, // THERE ARE 7 AGENTS TOTAL
        "0 properties": 0,
        "1 property": 2,
        "2 properties": 1,
        "3 or more properties": 4
    },
    {
        type: "host",
        count: 5, // THERE ARE 5 HOSTS TOTAL
        "0 properties": 0,
        "1 property": 2,
        "2 properties": 0,
        "3 or more properties": 3
    }
]

The result will firstly group by type and for each grouped type we will have sub grouped by the ranges, which could then be rendered into a table/matrix !
I have already done this with a matrix of separate requests, one for each count !
This code above is obviously not correct and won't run. Does anyone know how to do this ?
Daniel

What do you mean by "matrix of separate requests, one for each count" ? What are your counts? 10, 20, 30, etc.? What is your expected output?

I added a small edit the the question under the code, does that make more sense ?

Your edit doesn't help in any way. (1) You've added a field for "Above or Equal 30" without changing the actual $sum. (2) My question was What are your counts? & What is your expected output? (3) Do you want above & below for all counts? What is "all counts"?

I added desired result. Does that help make sense of it ?

Yes, lol that helps a lot. Much clearer now. Retracting my close vote. Btw, for host, there are 2 who have property: 1 (you have put that as only 1 has property: 1) and your count: 5 wouldn't match with 0 + 1 + 0 + 3

@Aneroid you are right, whoops, 2 times 1 properties for host, i edited question to fix that error ! Thanks

One way to do it is to group the documents on type and for each range, get a count of how many elements meet the == 0, == 1, == 2, >= 3, criteria:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      count: { $count: {} },
      num_properties: { $push: "$properties" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "0 properties": {
        $size: {
          $filter: { input: "$num_properties", cond: { $eq: ["$$this", 0] } }
        }
      },
      "1 property": {
        $size: {
          $filter: { input: "$num_properties", cond: { $eq: ["$$this", 1] } }
        }
      },
      "2 properties": {
        $size: {
          $filter: { input: "$num_properties", cond: { $eq: ["$$this", 2] } }
        }
      },
      "3 or more properties": {
        $size: {
          $filter: { input: "$num_properties", cond: { $gte: ["$$this", 3] } }
        }
      },
      type: "$_id",
      _id: "$$REMOVE",
      num_properties: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Ok cool, gonna try this Monday/Tuesday, I'll be back !

Hi again @aneroid , I will come to this answer, I assure you, just other major issues have crammed my time, its a 100% requirement figure this out for us, as Arnold says, I'll be back !
